# Hide shop_id field for specific group

Tags: xml, openerp-7

I'm trying to hide the field `shop_id` from the order view form for a specific group, I have tried with `attrs`, `replace`, `attribute=invisible`, etc, but the field remains visible.

This is my last code in a new inherited view, all the other fields are restricted correctly but I can't do it with `shop_id` field.

Help appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="sale_order_restrict_view">
      <field name="name">sale.order.restrict.view</field>
      <field name="model">sale.order</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
      <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('motoscoot_restrictions.group_barcelona_level0') ])]" />
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="price_unit" position="attributes" >
          <attribute name="readonly">True</attribute>
        </field>
        <field name="discount" position="attributes" >
          <attribute name="readonly">True</attribute>
        </field>
        <xpath expr="//group/field[@name='shop_id']" position='replace'>
          <field name="shop_id"  invisible="1"/>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//page[@string='Other Information']" position='attributes'>
          <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Make sure that the field is in that view, maybe it is added by other module

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the view priority, i changed to:

priority" eval="20"

Answer (score -1):

I think the better solution is, You need to create new group in that add all those groups to whom you want to give access of that field.

```
<record model="res.groups" id="group_hq_manager_ept">
    <field name="name">HQ Manager</field>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_hq_user_ept'))]"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>                        
</record>
```

In this manner you can create new groups with extending the functionality of an existing groups. Add this xml code to your view it will create groups while you upgrading module.

Then you just simply assign that newly created group to the field and your  will get desire effect.

```
<xpath expr="//group/field[@name='shop_id']" position='repalce'>
    <field name="shop_id"  groups="group_hq_manager_ept"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Aha, i'll try, but when you say : <field name="implied_ids" , what i have to put here?

Comment: It's use for inheritance, if you want to inherit any groups like base_user or pos_user, <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_hq_user_ept'))]"/> values you need to gives are external id of the groups with module name.

Comment: this is optional you can remove that line also.